# downloadURL from Firebase Storage is nil after successfully uploading a file

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm new to firebase and I'm facing a problem here.

I have successfully uploaded my image to firebase storage already, however, I need to get the downloadurl at once and post it to the database. And I'm not sure why it doesn't work within that closure.

The following is my code:-

```
   func CreateNewChatRoom(user: User, caption: String, data: Data){
    let filePath = "\(user.uid)/\(Int(NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)).jpg"
    let metaData = StorageMetadata()
    metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"
    let reference = storageRef.child(filePath)

    reference.putData(data, metadata: metaData) { (metadata, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        reference.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
            if let error = error{
                print("Error : \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            else{
                if let downloadURL = url?.absoluteString {
                    let idRoom = self.BASE_REF.child("rooms").childByAutoId()
                    idRoom.setValue(["caption":caption, "thumbnailUrlFromStorage": self.storageRef.child(metadata!.path!).description,"fileUrl": downloadURL])
                }
            }
        })

    }

}
```

Comment: So what results are you getting? Does your code get the url correctly?

Comment: I get fileUrl = nil, and i'm not sure why it doesn't execute the closure block. I've checked my firebase storage, the image is well uploaded.

Comment: and i keep on getting this error message from the xcode console : BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C6.1:2][0x7fbcf8d25db0] get output frames failed, state 8196

Comment: And if you make a print(downloadURL) just at the beginning of your if let, do you see the downloadURL value of do you have nil?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and I found the following solution,
I hope it is useful to someone.
Swift 5

import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseFirestore

typealias AddStoryResult = (Bool, Error?) -> Void
typealias UploadImageResult = (StorageMetadata?, Error?) -> Void

class StoryFirebaseAPI {

```
static let storage = Storage.storage()
static var downloadUrlString: URL?
var image: UIImage?

let photoUri = "smth uri path"

uploadImage(image, photoUriString: photoUri) { (metadata: StorageMetadata?, error: Error?) in
    
    guard let metadata = metadata else {
        if let error = error {
            print("Error occured: \(error)")
        }
        completion(false, error)
        return
    }

    // and at this point I have print(downloadUrlString)
    
    completion(true, nil)
}
```

}

extension StoryFirebaseAPI {

```
func uploadImage(_ image: UIImage, photoUriString: String, completion: @escaping UploadImageResult) {
    
    guard let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) else {
        print("smth error")
        completion(nil, nil)
        return
    }
    
    let storageRef = storage.reference().child(photoUriString)
    
    let imageMetadata = StorageMetadata()
    imageMetadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"
    
    storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: imageMetadata) { (storageMetadata, error) in
        
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }
        
        guard let unwrappedMetadata = storageMetadata else {
            print("smth error")
            print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }
        
        
        storageRef.downloadURL { url, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            } else {
                if let url = url {
                    downloadUrlString = url
                    completion(unwrappedMetadata, nil)
                }
            }
        }
        print("Image uploaded successfully")
    }
}
```

}